# how to find cholesky of a matrix?

Tags: matlab

i have n number of matrix and i want to find square root each.but my algorithm  need cholesky .i am getting error  that matrix is not positive definite.i converted diagonal element into real one.still I'm getting same error. is there any other way to find cholesky of a matrix?

Comment: If your matrix is not definite positive, you cannot use Cholesky factorization (by definition). Use another decomposition (eigenvalues, LU, QR,...).

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is a long way from being positive definite, there's nothing you can do - the Cholesky factorization is based on the assumption that it is positive definite.

Often though, a matrix is basically positive definite, but due to some small numerical issue is very slightly non-symmetric. If this is the problem you're running into, you can force it (let's say it's called `x`) to be symmetric by saying `x = (x+x')/2`.

Hope that helps!